# What do the demonstratives (determiners) refer to here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Recording engineers and musicians have learned to create special effects that tickle our brains. **These special effects** are similar in principle to **3Dart, motions, or visual illusions,** **none of which** have been around long enough for our brains to have evolved special mechanisms to perceive **them.**

Here, which do **none of which** and **them**  refer to?

**Only** 3Dart,motionpictures,orvisualillusions?
OR
**Both**
special effects and 3Dart,motionpictures,orvisualillusions ?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'none of which' and the word 'them' refer directly to 3Dart, motions or visual illusions from a grammatical standpoint. The phrase, 'none of which have been around long enough for our brains to have evolved special mechanisms to perceive them' is an adjectival phrase describing '3Dart, motions or visual illusions', which is the object of the prepositional phrase, 'similar to'.

They also refer in an indirect way to 'These special effects'. The author says that the musical special effects are similar *in principle* to 3Dart, motions or visual illusions. The 'principal' the author refers to that makes them similar is that they have not been around long enough for our brains to have evolved special mechanisms to perceive them.

The word 'them' is called a resumptive pronoun. To me it seems redundant in the sentence. I prefer to write

> These special effects are similar in principle to 3Dart, motions, or visual illusions, none of which have been around long enough for our brains to have evolved special mechanisms to perceive.

Comment: I don't agree that it's better to omit _these_. While your version is perfectly good, I find it easier to understand with the resumptive pronoun _them_ on the end of the long relative clause and its embedded infinite clause.

Answer (score 0):

**none of which** normally refers to the list of things immediately preceding it: in this case "3D art, motion pictures and visual illusions". It is less clear for **them**, but I'd say it applies to the same list.